# Firebase: proper way to access child elements' data

Tags: firebase

I'm a bit confused on how to access some data I'm creating with my Firebase. I'm trying to make a simple Texas Hold 'em game and I currently have data structured as:

```
game
    player
        unique push() id
            name
            chips
            hand               
        unique push() id
```

I can get an array with all the unique player objects and their data, but I cant figure out how to get at the data in the unique IDs.

Answer (score 2):

You can use on() with value (useful for primitives and small objects):

```
firebaseRef.child('game/player').on('value', function(groupSnap) {
    groupSnap.forEach(function(snap) {
       console.log( snap.name() + ' has ' + snap.val().chips + ' chips ' );
    });
});
```

on() with child_added (useful for large data sets where you just want changes and not the entire bulk each time there is an update):

```
firebaseRef.child('game/player').on('child_added', function(snap) {
   console.log( snap.name() + ' has ' + snap.val().chips + ' chips ' );
});
```

Or go right for the kill by navigating to the child directly:

```
firebaseRef.child('game/player/player1/chips').on('value', function(snap) {
    console.log('player1 has '+snap.val()+' chips');
});
```

The [tutorial](https://www.firebase.com/tutorial/#gettingstarted), followed by this section on [reading data](https://www.firebase.com/docs/reading-data.html) is really where you need to start out to get primed on these basic concepts.

Comment: The link to the tutorial is not working or pointing to the old docs, can you please check and correct? + the `name()` should now be `key`?